# How to convert the Raw Sql query to Django Model

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-queryset

My models.py:

```
class TheaterShowTimings(models.Model):
    showname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    showtime = models.TimeField()  # stores only time
    theatershowtimingsid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.theatershowtimingsid


class MovieActiveDays(models.Model):
     date = models.DateField()  # stores single only date
     moviedetails = models.ForeignKey(MovieDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     theaterbase = models.ForeignKey(TheaterBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     activedayid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
     def __str__(self):
        return self.activedayid

class ActiveShowTimings(models.Model):
     TheaterShowTimings = models.ForeignKey(TheaterShowTimings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     MovieActiveDays = models.ForeignKey(MovieActiveDays, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     activeshowid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
     def __str__(self):
        return self.activeshowid
```

My views.py:

```
 show_name_list = TheaterShowTimings.objects.raw('SELECT distinct * FROM Book_TheaterShowTimings where theatershowtimingsid IN (select TheaterShowTimings_id from Book_ActiveShowTimings where MovieActiveDays_id IN (select activedayid from Book_MovieActiveDays where date = "2016-12-19")) order by showtime ASC')
```

The above query in *views.py* is **working** fine. But, I want to convert it into a django queryset. please help me, I`m stuck at converting that raw sql query to queryset.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making use of `ManyToManyField`.

Only two steps is needed:

1. Create a `ManyToManyField` fields `movieActiveDays` for `TheaterShowTimings`.
2. Make query with the new `movieActiveDays` field.

Model definition

```
class TheaterShowTimings(models.Model):
    showname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    showtime = models.TimeField()  # stores only time
    theatershowtimingsid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    # many to many fields to MovieActiveDays
    movieActiveDays = models.ManyToManyField('MovieActiveDays', through='ActiveShowTimings')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.theatershowtimingsid
```

Query:

```
TheaterShowTimings.objects.filter(movieActiveDays__date='2016-12-19').distinct()
```

Comment: Worth noting that adding this field does not change the database structure at all; it will use the existing through table.